# how to install Flex (lex) in Debian

Tags: debian, flex-lexer

I have **Debian (Kali linux 1.0)**, I thought that **Bison** and **Flex** should be already installed but **Flex** (lex) wasn't, I tried to install it using **apt-get** and **aptitude** but it keeps saying "Package flex is not available". how do I install **flex** ? or is there another way to work with **lex** ?

P.S: I did try `apt-get update` and `aptitude update`

and here's my system information:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux oldstable-updates (sid)
Release:        oldstable-updates
Codename:       sid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to the Debian web site, you can find the list of [development software packages](http://packages.debian.org/stable/devel/). It lists 3 alternatives for Bison, and also 3 for Flex.

However, [Kali](http://www.kali.org/tag/debian/) is not identical to Debian, so maybe you should look at their web site to get the information.

If the worst comes to the worst, you can download [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/releases) and compile and install it for yourself.  It is very simple to build.

Comment: thanks, I downloaded it (mine is old-stable) and it seems to work fine. :)